# How to use typescript generics to restrict a type to keys of an object who's value extends a given type

Tags: typescript

I have a react hook below which will return item route properties from a react navigation route. I currently use the type `CartRouteProps` which in turn uses the specific RouteName ***"CartScreen"***. This works but I have multiple routes which have item props and I would prefer to make it more generic and allow any route with properties that extend ItemProps.

Is there a way where I can use Typescript Generics to restrict the RouteName to only routes who's value extends ItemProps?

**Navigator.tsx**

```
type ItemProps = {
  id: number
}

type AppStackParamList = {
  MainScreen: undefined;
  ResultsScreen: undefined;
  OrderScreen: ItemProps;
  CartScreen: ItemProps;
  PaymentScreen: ItemProps;
  ConfirmationScreen: undefined;

};

...
```

**useItem.hook.ts**

```
import { RouteProp, useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AppStackParamList } from "../Navigator";

export type CartRouteProps = RouteProp<
  AppStackParamList,
  "CartScreen"
>;

export const useItem = () => {
  const route = useRoute<CartRouteProps>();
  const itemParams = route.params;

  return itemParams;
};
```